# How can I ensure that one SSIS task is among the first to start during parallel processing?

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS master package that starts up multiple subordinate tasks. There are lots of packages that can all run in parallel, and for the most part it doesn't matter which ones run when. There are *N* worker threads available, and about *N*x3 packages to run, so SSIS will start *N* of them at a time.

One of them, though, takes quite a bit longer to run than the others.

[image]

So I **always** want that package to be one of the first to start, not one that's hanging around waiting for an available thread to run.

I can break it out into it's own parallel sequence container, and that *seems* to work, but I don't know that it will **always** work.

Is there a way I can be certain that the longest running job will always take one of the first available threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is, there isn't a way, that I'm aware of, to provide a weighting to which thread it should pick first.

But, you can certain change the design to make it so. In your sequence container, any of the N tasks in there could get the nod to start. But if you drop a sequence container inside the existing container and move the the low level tasks into it, they'll all run in parallel so then you just need to ensure the long running task has enough time to spin up before the parallelized container fires off. So, add a Script Task precursor to the inner container to sleep for 3, 5, 8 seconds whatever you think is likely enough delay to give the long task adequate time to start.

```
int delayInSeconds = 3;
int delayInMillSeconds = delayInSeconds*1000;
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delayInMillSeconds);
```

And obviously, make the delay an SSIS variable so you can tweak the delay without altering the script.

Assuming this is dimensional loading, I have a table that drives this behavior but a bit different. My sequence containers look like

```
Execute SQL Task (Get outstanding tasks)
Foreach Recordset (Take a task)
    Execute Package Task (do work, final step records task is complete)
```

I have N parallel processing sequence containers out there. If I flag something as a big job, it's going to be the only thing in the list of outstanding tasks

```
PackageName|ContainerName|Task Name|Priority
P1         |C0           |Long job | 1
P1         |C1           |Long job2| 1
P1         |C2           |Lil job1 | 10
P1         |C2           |Lil job2 | 20
P1         |C2           |Lil job3 | 30
```

Running the smaller jobs in sequence allows me to leave some breathing room for the server but that stack of jobs will still finish long before the long running threads are complete.

Comment: The precursor task was kick in the pants my brain needed. Thank you!